# .apply(lambda..., strftime produces None

Tags: python, pandas, strftime

I am trying to change the format of the date and time values I am receiving from the sensor. I initially receive it as string and i convert it into datetime and then try to apply strftime. When I do this in Jupyter notebook on set of values it works fine but when I implement it in my code it breaks. Here is my code:

```
import json
import socket
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Establish connection with Database
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Production.db', echo=False)

# Establish connecton with Spider
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind(('192.168.130.35', 8089))

# Receive data while sensor is live
while True:
    message, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    # Create empty list to hold data of interest
    objs_json = []
    # Record only data where tracked_objects exist within json stream
    if b'tracked_objects' in message:
        stream = json.loads(message)
        if not stream:
            break
        # Append all data into list and process through parser
        objs_json += stream
        print("Recording Tracked Object")

        # Parsing json file with json_normalize object
        objs_df = json_normalize(objs_json, record_path='tracked_objects',
                                 meta=[['metadata', 'serial_number'], 'timestamp'])
        # Renaming columns
        objs_df = objs_df.rename(
            columns={"id": "object_id", "position.x": "x_pos", "position.y": "y_pos",
                     "person_data.height": "height",
                     "metadata.serial_number": "serial_number", "timestamp": "timestamp"})

        # Selecting columns of interest
        objs_df = objs_df.loc[:, ["timestamp", "serial_number", "object_id", "x_pos", "y_pos", "height"]]

        # Converting datatime into requested format
        objs_df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(objs_df["timestamp"])
        objs_df["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %Hh:%Mm:%Ss.%f")[:-3])

        # Writting the data into SQlite db
        objs_df.to_sql('data_object', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
    # In case there is no tracks, print No Tracks in console.
    else:
        print("No Object Tracked")
    # Empty the list and prepare it for next capture
    objs_json = []
```

Here is the error message i am getting:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\slavi\PycharmProjects\ProRail_FInal_POC\pythreads\runner.py", line 15, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\slavi\PycharmProjects\ProRail_FInal_POC\ObjectStream.py", line 46, in objectstream
    objs_df["timestamp"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %Hh:%Mm:%Ss.%f")[:-3])
  File "C:\Users\slavi\PycharmProjects\ProRail_FInal_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4049, in apply
    return self._constructor(mapped, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
  File "C:\Users\slavi\PycharmProjects\ProRail_FInal_POC\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 299, in __init__
    "index implies {ind}".format(val=len(data), ind=len(index))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 0, index implies 1
```

Any idea how do I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share what `message` is?

Comment: pnv - i already did. its right below the code. Are you referring to some other message?